# Replace pattern matching issue in Scala

Tags: scala, slick

I have a specific query in slick defined like:

```
var query = for {
      a <- Assets if a.ownerId === partyIdLoggedInUser || a.userId === partyIdLoggedInUser
      m <- a.model
      l <- a.location
      ad <- l.address
      sl <- SpecificLocations if sl.assetId === a.id
} yield (a._type ~ m.make ~ m.model ~ a.serialNumber ~ 
    a.linkQualityValue.? ~ a.activationDate.? ~ l.id ~ 
    l.description ~ ad.id ~ ad.street ~ ad.number ~ 
    ad.zipcode ~ ad.city ~ ad.country ~ ad.geoLocationId.? ~ 
    sl.building.? ~ sl.floor.? ~ sl.room.? ~ sl.other.?)
```

Later, based on some parameters, I do some pattern matchings and apply some additional filters to this query, eg:

```
query = serialNumber match {
  case Some(serialNumber) => query.where(a => a._4 === serialNumber)
  case None => query
}
```

Well, I want to make these checking(s) shorter by using a map:

`query = serialNumber.map(s => query.where(a => a._1 === s))`

I don't understand why my map solution is not accepted. Do you see any issue?

It says that `found Option[Query[....]] but required Query[...]`

Comment: serialNumber is a Option right?

Comment: The issue is that serialNumber.map(...) returns Option[_] and query is Query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
query = serialNumber.map(s => query.where(a => a._1 === s)).getOrElse(query)
```

Answer (score 2):

`map` takes `Option[A]` to `Option[B]` while you want to take `Option[A]` to `A`. You could use `map` and then `getOrElse`.